# Sencha SDK Tool / JSBuilder - include all files with *

Tags: extjs, jsbuilder

Using Sencha Touch 1, I am having to manually create my app.jsb3 file (and add all linked JavaScript files to that .jsb3 file) in order to use jsbuilder to minify all files.

Anybody know the correct syntax to allow use of a wildcard (.*) (referred to as a Filter) in order to easily include all files in a folder?

I know the docs here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/JSBuilder2/JSB2FileFormat.txt
state that ".*" can be used - but I've had no joy:

```
"files": [
  {"path": "views/", "name": "file1.js"},
  {"path": "views/", "name": "file2.js"}, // currently manually adding each file
  ...
  {"path": "views/", "name": ".*"},  // include all?
  {"path": "views/.*"},              // include all?
]
```

The docs only show filters in relation to listing resources, but not also for listing files - may be why!